# [KeyboardDatePicker]: How to increase font size of KeyboardDatePicker in material-ui/pickers in react

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to increase the font size of the label in the KeyboardDatePicker component using below code however it doesn't work for me. Any solution would be appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ty1.png)

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import { DatePicker, KeyboardDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';


const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    '& label': {
      fontSize: '26px',
    },
  },
});

export function CustomDatePicker(props) {
    return (
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          {...pickerProps}
          format='yyyy/MM/dd'
          mask='____/__/__'
          {...props}
        />
    )
}

export default compose(
    memo,
    withStyles(styles),
  )(CustomDatePicker);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [API doc](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker), props would be passed down to material-ui TextField component. So, you need yo modify fontSize according to the `TextField` component as below:

First create a new object of style, contaning your prefered font size:

```
 customTextField: {
    "& input::placeholder": {
      fontSize: "20px"
    }
  }
```

then assign it to `KeyboardDatePicker` component:

```
 <KeyboardDatePicker
          {...pickerProps}
          format='yyyy/MM/dd'
          mask='____/__/__'
          {...props}
          classes={{ root: classes.customTextField }}

        />
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-date-picker-forked-3l1qh?file=/demo.js:1773-1831)